# How do I manage two datepickers if I want to set another datepicker according to date selected in first? Bootstrap datepicker

Tags: datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

This is my code. I want to set a date according to date selected in first datepicker. How do I do this?

```
<input type="text" placeholder="From" class="week" id="dt1">
<input type="text" placeholder="To" class="week" id="dt2">

$(function() {
  $("#dt1").datepicker({
    minDate: "-",
    maxViewMode: "weeks",
    format: "dd-mm-yy",
    clearBtn: true,
    orientation: "bottom auto"
      /*calendarWeeks: true,
      todayHighlight: true*/
  });

  $("#dt2").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    endDate: "today"
  })
});
```

Comment: Do you mean something like a linked picker where the `#To` can't be above the `#From`?

Comment: No. @William-H-M. I will give you an example. If i want to pickup a date for week. So if i select date in #from datepicker input, #to datepicker should automatically show only next 7 days.

Comment: Ohh ok ok could you please tell which picker are you using as most of them have different way of do things

Comment: @William-H-M I am using bootstrap datepicker. and following links support that datepicker.  1) <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/css/bootstrap-datepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">  2) <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
   3) <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
   4) <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.5.0/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so with the option given you just must "listen" when the dates changed that's basically what the events provided does, so we're going to use [`changeDate`](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/events.html#changedate) on both `#From` and `#To` Picker to just allow select that week dates.

**Note 1:** I recommend you to disable the `#To` to avoid picker dates ahead, should be the same without it though.

**Note 2:** I removed the codes that you have commented out.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="From" class="week" id="dt1">
<input type="text" placeholder="To" disabled="disabled" class="week" id="dt2">

$(function() {
  $("#dt1").datepicker({
    minDate: "-",
    maxViewMode: "weeks",
    format: "dd-mm-yy",
    clearBtn: true,
  }).on('changeDate', function(event) {
    $('#dt2').removeAttr('disabled'); //We enable our #To Picker
    var newDate = new Date(event.date);
    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + 6); //We add 6 days to our selected date
    $("#dt2").datepicker("setStartDate", event.date); //Set as start point that selected day 
    $("#dt2").datepicker("setEndDate", newDate); //Set the final "MaxDate

  });
   //We do the same for this one but backwards to avoid puttin "invalid" dates
  $("#dt2").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
    endDate: "today"
  }).on('changeDate', function(event) {
    var newDate = new Date(event.date);
    newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() - 6);

    //You can alway remove this line to allow your user to select any start date
    $("#dt1").datepicker("setStartDate", newDate);
    //And here we set our max date on From picker so he doesn't again enter "invalid" dates
    $("#dt1").datepicker("setEndDate", event.date);

  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you boss. Your code is just working as expected!!! Thank you so much. Thank you for your help.